# Robospice/ Retrofit background service accessing database

Tags: android, robospice, retrofit

I've successfully created a **Retrofit** API Rest client making both *GET* & *POST* calls and also incorporated that into **Robospice** as a background service.

However, I want the **Robospice** service to connect to the database and asynchronously persist the retrieved objects from the *GET* call. Using the **Retrofit** `Callback` class seems the obvious way but connecting to the database requires `Context` and I"m concerned about leaking the `Context`.

so, what would be the best approach to get the **Robospice** `SpiceService` to persist data to the database both prior to and post a request being processed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, as I'm batching the various *Rest* API service calls to save radio ([Reto Meier Dev Bytes: Efficient Data Transfers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSIB2pDvH3E)), I call the Rest API services  (`RetrofitSpiceService`s) from within a controller `Robospice SpiceService` containing both the reference to the `DatabaseHelper` (requiring `Context`) and the respective `Retrofit` callbacks for the *Rest* services.

This way, the controller service handles all the triggering (`AlarmManager` triggers the controller service) and persisting to DB and the Rest services can shut themselves down as normal without knowledge of `context`, `database` or suchlike.

For @lion789: 
I have 4 models each with a corresponding API call to sync with the server (1 **POST**, 3 **GET**). 
To handle these sync calls, I have an `IntentService` that contains 4 `SpiceManager` attribute and 4 **Retrofit** `Callback` classes - one for each model/API call. 
The `IntentService` is passed an `Enum` indicating a sequence of APIs that should be called. 
 
The `IntentService` calls the appropriate `SpiceManager` which runs, then the `Callback` triggers the persistence and calls an `IntentService` method to trigger the next API call in the sequence.

A **lot** of this is abstracted and interfaced as I use it for my Auth and Push Registration code so it's a bit of a nightmare to describe but it's been working pretty well thus far.

Comment: Hey do you have an examples of this... I am actually trying to use Robospice as well to cache the data with Retrofit

Comment: Edited my answer to provide more info for @Lion789. Let me know if you need further info.

Comment: thanks, was actually curious, if I have okHttpClient and retrofit, does the caching happen automatically meaning I do not need to use Robospice then?

Comment: @lion789 not too sure what you mean by caching. If you're talking about persisting sync data in the DB, I'm rolling my own DatabaseHelper not the `Robospice` one. If you're going that way, look at `OrmLite` from which the `Robospice` database helper inherits.

If you're talking about response caching (in a local file), that can be done just via `Retrofit` (see Jesse Wilson's gist https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/5889518)

Comment: Oh ok thanks, yeah I meant response caching... and I have to play around with jesse's response because it was not working... but someone told me it was automatically cached if you just have the two libs and specify it in the headers of the request calls in retrofit... that is why I was not sure

Answer (score 2):

Your question is really fuzzy to me. I don't understand why you can't use the normal persistence mechanism of RS. If you do so, it's pretty easy to persist your data when requests have been executed.

Maybe I am missing something. So, if your requirement is really to persist data yourself, then the approach you propose looks right. You could inject the spice service itself inside your request (see how addRequest is override in RetrofitSpiceService for instance). The request would then hold a context that can be used for persistence inside a callback, or inside the request itself.

Recently I have coded a POST request using retrofit and RS. I changed the signature of the POST request to return a Void. Then slightly modified the retrofit converter to deal with that case and return null. The request received the spice service via injection as mentioned earlier and could do some actions on the database.

Here is some code to inject the application inside a request from within a spice service.

```
    @Override
    public void addRequest(CachedSpiceRequest<?> request,
                    Set<RequestListener<?>> listRequestListener) {
            if (request.getSpiceRequest() instanceof MySpiceRequest) {
                    MySpiceRequest<?> mySpiceRequest = (MySpiceRequest<?>) request
                                    .getSpiceRequest();
                    mySpiceRequest.setApplication(this.getApplication());
            }
            super.addRequest(request, listRequestListener);
    }
```